# How to calculate log of matrix but ignore values that equal 0

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A 3x3 that has some element equal 0. And I want to calcualte log(A). But we know that log (0) is not identify. So I want to calculate log of matrix A that ignore elements equal 0. And if element equal 0. I want to set log(0) =0. How to implement it in matlab. Thank all. Example :

```
A=[3 2 3
   3 0 2
   4 5 0]
Log(A)=[    1.0986    0.6931    1.0986
            1.0986      0       0.6931
            1.3863    1.6094         0]
```

Comment: But `log(0)~=0` and `exp(0)~=0`.  What you propose will just cause trouble later in your computations. Better to go with the flow and let `log(0)==-Inf`. You can dispute the validity of Matlab's computation in this respect but at least it clearly shows that you have taken the logarithm of an exceptional value.

Comment: Yes I know. But if I did not ignore element that equal zero, my calculate is fail. In my case, I don't want to calulate element that equal 0. So I set them equal 0 to ignore them

Comment: Just nitpicking - but `logm` is there to calculate the log of a *matrix*. You are actually performing logarithm elementwise.

Answer (score 6):

Let's first set to 1 the elements of A that are 0:

```
log(A+(A==0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `NaN`, as `log(NaN) = NaN`:

```
A = [3 2 3;
     3 0 2;
     4 5 0];

A(A==0) = NaN; 
B = log(A);
```

But you should consider the comment of High Performance Mark. I personally would keep the `NaN`. If you really want it:

```
B(isnan(B)) = 0;
```

returns:

```
B =

    1.0986    0.6931    1.0986
    1.0986         0    0.6931
    1.3863    1.6094         0
```

Comment: Manipulating NaN or Inf slows down the arithmetic operations by an order of magnitude. Avoid them if you want high performances.

Comment: @user2987828 but you are aware that you're doing exactly the same (I just haven't recognized that)? `A = A+(A==0)` and `A(A==0) = NaN` are similar, so I don't get the point of your comment.

Comment: @user2987828: my solution is even faster!

Comment: `A = A+(A==0)` and `A(A==0) = 1` are similar. No NaN involved in my answer.

Comment: @user2987828 I'm now at home, where I have Matlab 2013b and for this version I have to say: you're right. For Matlab 2012a, which I have at work, you're wrong. What version do you have?

Comment: matlab2009b usually. Adding booleans to reals is a thing I use a lot, so I am pretty sure it is the same in matlab2007b and matlab2010b.

Answer (score 1):

The straight forward approach:

```
B = zeros(size(A))
zl = find(A)
B(zl) = log(A(zl))
```

Comment: Well, that was a bug, not a feature. (edited the answer). Thanks @HighPerformanceMark